# Return original flow file in NiFi ExecuteStreamCommand

Tags: python, apache-nifi

I have a Python script I'm attempting to run in NiFi using the `ExecuteStreamCommand` processor. When the file runs into an issue in the `try` block, I want it to return the original flow file in the `except` block. Normally, I would just do `sys.stdout.write(flow_file)` in the except block, but the issue pops up when I attempt to read it into the system because the utf-8 encoding is messed up.

How do I return a flow file without invoking `sys.stdout.write(flow_file)`? I also tried to just do `pass` but it also fails to return the flow file as anything but a 0 byte file. It will come out the output stream path, but it's still just a 0 byte file which is not what I need.

**Current script**

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import sys

try:
    flow_file = sys.stdin.read()
    sys.stdout.write(str(flow_file))
except:
    # sys.stdout.write(flow_file) # returned 0 byte
    pass # returned 0 byte
```

Comment: i advice you to do `sys.exit(1)` (for example) in case of exception. in this case original flow file will be redirected to `nonzero status` relation automatically.

Comment: @daggett but it still comes out as a 0 byte file when I do `sys.exit(1)` in the exception, and I need it to return the original flow file in either the nonzero status or output stream.

Comment: Does `sys.stdin.buffer.read()` work?

Comment: @mattyb no I tried `flow_file = sys.stdin.buffer.read() \\ sys.stdout.buffer.write(flow_file)` and it just returns an empty 0 byte file.